# wp_actionscheduler_actions -> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'scheduled_date_gmt'

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, wordpress-database

wp_actionscheduler_actions - when I activated wp mail plugin it shows error message duplicate primary key, WordPress user cant created, WordPress plugin not working properly, WordPress database having two database engine immodb and MyISAM.
after converting to myisam to innodb, wp_actionscheduler_actions in table following error message showing

`#1067 - Invalid default value for 'scheduled_date_gmt'`

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your MySql database is installed with a "strict" mode on.

You can run the command below from your command line terminal or if you have  PHPMyAdmin installed and you have a root access, simply login to phpmyadmin localhost/general settings, click "SQL" in the top horizontal navigational menu and  run the command below:

```
 SET @@global.sql_mode="";
```

Of course you can use the same way to reverse it by setting any strict access on as you wish, by inserting commands in the double quotes of the same command.
For example:

```
 SET @@global.sql_mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY";
```

Please refer to your MYSQL version for the non depreciated values.